# method on model returning empty during rspec tests even though it should have a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am doing the following rspec test to test my '#clubs' method

```
context "#clubs" do
  it "returns the users associated Clubs" do
    club = create(:club)

    user = club.host

    expect(user.clubs).to contain(club)
  end
end
```

The method in my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :host_clubs, :class_name => 'Club', :inverse_of => :host
  has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteer_clubs, :class_name => 'Club', :inverse_of => :volunteers

  def clubs
    [host_clubs, volunteer_clubs].flatten
  end
end
```

When I run the test and use `p club.host`, it returns the user as expected, however I cannot see why calling `user.clubs => []` returns an empty array. Here is the factory for context.

```
factory :host, class: User do |f|
  f.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  f.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
  f.email { Faker::Internet.email }
  f.password { Faker::Internet.password }
  f.role { "host" }
  f.onboarded_at { Date.today }

  after(:create) do |host|
    host.confirm_email_address
  end
end

factory :club, class: Club do |f|
  f.venue_type { "Primary school" }
  f.name { Faker::Company.name }
  f.address_1 { Faker::Address.street_address }
  f.city { Faker::Address.city }
  host
end
```

Can anyone give me a heads up to why it may not be returning the record?

It's worth noting that I am adding this test after the method was created. In the console the method behaves as expected.

Comment: Try `user.reload` before expecting the results in the test (yn)

Comment: @VenkatCh that worked perfectly thanks. Happy to accept that as an answer. I am wondering why the user needs to be reloaded though?

Comment: @DMH because you are working with a stale variable.

Comment: another thing I'd mention, use `describe` instead of `context` if you *describe* what a method does. Context is solely for special cases, like `context 'user has no clubs' -> it 'returns blank'`...

Comment: @TheCha͢mp completely agree cheers.

Comment: @DMH - I'm glad it helps! I am going to update it as an answer. Thanks for your encouragement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Making my comment as an answer with additional information)

Try `user.reload` before expecting the results in the test solves this issue.

This is because of `club` object is created independently from `user`. This is generally happens in `rspec` tests.